# Koopman's Theorem for Ionization energy and electron affinity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, ionization-energy

Why is [Koopman's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koopmans%27_theorem) a reliable approximation for ionization energy but unreliable for electron affinity? I understand that it has to do with cancellation of errors by orbital relaxation and electron correlation, but why do they cancel more in one case than the other?

Answer (score 6):

I will present a more quantitative version of the (mostly verbal) argument given at the end of Sec. 3.3.1 in *Modern Quantum Chemistry* by Szabo & Ostlund. The argument goes like this.

Let us first deal with the ionization energy. The exact ground state energy of the $N$-electron system can be written as
$$
E(N)=E_{\text{HF}}(N)+E_{\text{corr}}(N) \ ,
$$
where the correlation energy measures the deviation from the HF energy. Due to the variational character of HF, we have $E(N)<E_{\text{HF}}(N)$, hence $E_{\text{corr}}(N)<0$.
Similarly, for the $(N-1)$-electron system, we can write
$$
\begin{aligned}
E(N-1)&=E_{\text{HF}}(N-1)+E_{\text{corr}}(N-1) \\
&={\cal{E}}(N-1)+E_{\text{relax}}(N-1)+E_{\text{corr}}(N-1) \ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $E_{\text{HF}}(N-1)$ is the HF energy of the $(N-1)$-electron system (that we do not actually calculate), and ${\cal{E}}(N-1)$ is the HF-like energy calculated with the HF orbitals of the $N$-electron system:
$$
{\cal{E}}(N-1)=\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\langle\phi_k^{(N)}|\hat{h}|\phi_k^{(N)}\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k,l=1}^{N-1}{\Big[}\langle\phi_k^{(N)}\phi_l^{(N)}|\hat{v}|\phi_k^{(N)}\phi_l^{(N)}\rangle-\langle\phi_k^{(N)}\phi_l^{(N)}|\hat{v}|\phi_l^{(N)}\phi_k^{(N)}\rangle{\Big]} \ .
$$
Once again, due to variational reasons, $E_{\text{HF}}(N-1)<{\cal{E}}(N-1)$, so $E_{\text{relax}}(N-1)<0$.
Then the exact ionization energy can be written as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta_\text{IP}
&=E(N-1)-E(N) \\
&={\cal{E}}(N-1)-E_{\text{HF}}(N)+E_{\text{relax}}(N-1)+E_{\text{corr}}(N-1)-E_{\text{corr}}(N) \\
&=\Delta_\text{IP,Koopmans}+E_{\text{relax}}(N-1)+E_{\text{corr}}(N-1)-E_{\text{corr}}(N) \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The important thing here to realize is that the magnitude of correlation energy always increases with the number of particles. This means that $|E_{\text{corr}}(N-1)|<|E_{\text{corr}}(N)|$, so $E_{\text{corr}}(N-1)-E_{\text{corr}}(N)>0$, and it partially cancels the effect of orbital relaxation, thus reducing the error of $\Delta_\text{IP,Koopmans}$.

On the other hand, there is no such cancellation for electron affinities. We now have
$$
\begin{aligned}
E(N+1)&=E_{\text{HF}}(N+1)+E_{\text{corr}}(N+1) \\
&={\cal{E}}(N+1)+E_{\text{relax}}(N+1)+E_{\text{corr}}(N+1) \ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where ${\cal{E}}(N+1)$ is again calculated with the HF orbitals of the $N$-electron system (basically by adding a virtual orbital to the Slater determinant). Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta_\text{EA}
&=E(N)-E(N+1) \\
&=E_{\text{HF}}(N)-{\cal{E}}(N+1)-E_{\text{relax}}(N+1)+E_{\text{corr}}(N)-E_{\text{corr}}(N+1) \\
&=\Delta_\text{EA,Koopmans}-{\Big(}E_{\text{relax}}(N+1)+E_{\text{corr}}(N+1)-E_{\text{corr}}(N){\Big)} \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we see the problem: $|E_{\text{corr}}(N)|<|E_{\text{corr}}(N+1)|$, so $E_{\text{corr}}(N+1)-E_{\text{corr}}(N)<0$, and it does not cancel the orbital relaxation error at all, but actually adds to it.

This is why $\Delta_\text{EA,Koopmans}$ is a worse approximation to $\Delta_\text{EA}$ than $\Delta_\text{IP,Koopmans}$ to $\Delta_\text{IP}$.

Also, note that (contrary to occupied orbitals) canonical virtual HF orbitals and orbital energies are not uniquely defined, which makes ${\cal{E}}(N+1)$ somewhat ambiguous.

**Addendum**

Of course, ionization energies can be calculated by taking the difference of the HF energies, too:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta_\text{IP}
&=E(N-1)-E(N) \\
&=E_{\text{HF}}(N-1)-E_{\text{HF}}(N)+E_{\text{corr}}(N-1)-E_{\text{corr}}(N) \\
&=\Delta_\text{IP,HF}+E_{\text{corr}}(N-1)-E_{\text{corr}}(N) \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Despite the partial cancellation, $\Delta_\text{IP,Koopmans}$ is in general a poorer approximation to ionization energy than $\Delta_\text{IP,HF}$. The reason for this is that, in most cases, the magnitude of orbital relaxation effects is considerably larger than correlation effects, so $E_{\text{corr}}(N-1)-E_{\text{corr}}(N)$ cannot compensate $E_{\text{relax}}(N-1)$ well enough.

The outermost valence electrons are exceptions, since in their case, the two effects turn out to be of similar magnitude, meaning that $\Delta_\text{IP,Koopmans}$ can even outperform $\Delta_\text{IP,HF}$.

Two examples are given below for helium and neon.

\begin{array}{l|c|ccc}
 & \text{He} & & \text{Ne} &  \\ \hline
   & \Delta_\text{IP}(1s) \, / \, E_h & \Delta_\text{IP}(1s) \, / \, E_h & \Delta_\text{IP}(2s) \, / \, E_h & \Delta_\text{IP}(2p) \, / \, E_h \\ 
\hline
\text{Koopmans} & 0.918 & 32.772 & 1.930 & 0.850 \\
\text{HF} & 0.862 & 31.921 & 1.812 & 0.729 \\
\text{experiment} & 0.904 & 31.985 & 1.781 & 0.792
\end{array}

For helium, we used $\varepsilon_{1s}=-0.918 \, E_h$, $E_\text{HF}(\text{He})=-2.862 \, E_h$ and $E_\text{HF}(\text{He}^+)=-2.000 \, E_h$; for neon, see [*Phys. Rev.* **139 3A** 619 (1965)](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.139.A619), and NIST. We can see that the Koopmans approach works best for the outermost electrons, whose removal does not alter significantly the orbitals of other electrons.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Ecorr(N+1)−Ecorr(N)<0. I think the inequality here should be reversed. Is that right?

Comment: @ManfredArcane Thanks for the feedback. The inequality seems correct to me as it is. The absolute value of $E_\text{corr}(N+1)$ is larger than the absolute value of $E_\text{corr}(N)$ while both numbers are negative, which means $E_\text{corr}(N+1)<E_\text{corr}(N)$. The orbital relaxation energy is also negative, hence no cancellation in EA (contrary to the case of IP).